# Lentitud en respuesta de base de datos SQL Server desde PHP con ODBC

Tags: php, sql-server, xampp, wamp, odbc

He instalado XAMPP en mi equipo para ejecutar un sitio web PHP que se conecta vía ODBC a SQL Server, para lo cual activo pdo_odbc en el php.ini, mi sitio se conecta correctamente, pero sin importar lo pequeña que sea la consulta, incluso de 3 registros de una tabla, se demora más de 4 segundos.

Para la consulta utilizo AJAX.

Cuando me llevo el sitio a producción, esto no sucede, las consultas se comportan con la velocidad correcta (obviamente ya cada una dependiendo de su complejidad).

En mi ambiente local ya verifiqué que si hago esa misma consulta SQL directamente en el Management Studio, no se demora nada prácticamente.

Es como si tuviera un especie de problema con el servidor Apache pero la verdad ya no se que probar.

También he probado usando WAMP, pero pasa lo mismo.

Este mismo sitio también se conecta a través de una API Rest a una base de datos MySQL, pero en este caso todo va bien, no hay lentitud.

Les comparto el código que estoy utilizando:

Petición AJAX:

```
function listarCompania() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "../../controller/compania.php",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        data: {opcion: "listar"}
    })
    .done(function (data) {             
        if (data.length > 0) {   
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                $("#compania").append('<option value="'+ data[i].id +'">'+ data[i].nombre_comercial +'</option>');
            }
        }else{
            swal("Atención!", "No fue posible cargar las compañías", "error"); 
        }              
    });        
}
```

Archivo de conexión PHP:

```
<?php
class conexion {
private $instancia;
private $tipo = NULL;
function __construct($host, $database_name, $username, $password, $port) {
    $this->tipo = "sqlserver";
    $connection_string = "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=$host;DATABASE=$database_name;port=$port";
    $conn = odbc_connect($connection_string, $username, $password);
    $this->instancia = $conn;
}
function get_conexion() {
    return $this->instancia;
}
function cerrar() {
    odbc_close($this->instancia);
}
```

}

Controllador:

```
<?php
require_once '../model/compania.php';
include_once '../connection/data_connection.php';
define("DATABASE", "UNIVERSAL");
$funcion = new funcion(HOSTNAME,DATABASE,USERNAME,PASSWORD,PORT);
switch($_POST['opcion']){          
   case "listar" : echo ( $funcion->listar()); break;    
}
```

$funcion->cerrar();

Modelo:

```
<?php
require_once '../connection/connection.php';

class funcion extends conexion {

function __construct($host, $database_name, $username, $password, $port) {
    parent::__construct($host, $database_name, $username, $password, $port);
}

function listar() {
    $sql = "select id, nombre_comercial from compania where activo=1 order by orden asc";
    $result = odbc_exec(parent::get_conexion(), $sql);
    $data = array();
    $i = 0;
    while (odbc_fetch_row($result)) {
        $j = 1;
        $data [$i]['id'] = utf8_encode(odbc_result($result, $j));
        $j++;
        $data [$i]['nombre_comercial'] = utf8_encode(odbc_result($result, $j));
        $j++;
        $i++;
    }
    return json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: Lo que comentas puede deberse al `async: false,` que tienes en tu petición Ajax. Eso estaría bloqueando la UI mientras la petición se procesa, por el tiempo que ésta tarde. Prueba quitando esa línea en el código a ver cómo va. En tu código veo otras malas prácticas, pero luego te las comento si quieres.

Comment: Hola, ya hice la prueba quitando el async: false, pero sigue igual. Ese código es bastante viejito y si fue hecho con unas prácticas que a mi tampoco me agrandan mucho, pero si encantado de que recibir todas las recomendaciones posibles.

Comment: La otra mala práctica que veo es esto: `$("#compania").append('<option value="'+ data[i].id +'">'+ data[i].nombre_comercial +'</option>');`  dentro de un bucle. Cuando haces `append` a elementos del DOM éste se renderiza cada vez. Deberías construir los elementos en un DocumentFragment o en una cadena y hacer `append` una sola vez, fuera del bucle. De todos modos, en una consulta simple no debería notarse gran diferencia, pero nunca se sabe y, sea como sea, es otra mala práctica a corregir. Luego a modo de depuración, prueba a mandar los datos vía URL en la barra del navegador y dinos qué pasa

Comment: Si entiendo que en el código hay varias cosas que van agregando lentitud, pero realmente este mismo código en el ambiente de producción funciona bien (al menos con una velocidad razonable). De hecho en mi ambiente de desarrollo también estaba bien, es solo que reinstalé Windows hace poco y pasó esto. Una prueba que hice fue hacer la misma petición en un programa llamado Postman y es igual de lenta. La tabla apenas tiene 3 registros, no es normal que demore tanto

Comment: Puede haber algún elemento del entorno local (firewall u otro) que esté bloqueando algo. Quizá sería interesante revisar los logs.

Comment: En un controlador no deberías hacer `new funcion` ni `new conexion`. En teoría es un singleton y deberías usar `get_conexion`, pero como la implementación del singleton esta incompleta, te ves en la necesidad de hacer `new` y por lo tanto perder segundos mientras se crea una nueva conexión. Por otro lado, espero que `compania` no sea una vista.